# Why do all systemd experiences(drop-in configuration, add new service, etc) not work in initramfs?

Tags: systemd, initramfs

I am trying to customize a centos7.6 initramfs by adding a systemd service to do something before fsck get called or ideally immediately after the rootfs device get created.
I have experiences on how to configure systemd service, such as drop-in configurations, .wants dir, generators, etc,

but the weird thing is: all systemd experience just does not work,

I am pretty sure the initramfs(from [official site](https://cloud.centos.org/centos/7/images/CentOS-7-x86_64-GenericCloud-1907.qcow2c)) is using systemd, you can see the `/init -> /usr/lib/systemd/systemd` in the unpacked files of initramfs.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Dec  9 21:49 bin -> usr/bin/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Dec  9 21:49 dev/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2 Dec  9 21:49 early_cpio
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4.0K Dec  9 21:49 etc/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   23 Dec  9 21:49 init -> usr/lib/systemd/systemd*
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Dec  9 21:49 kernel/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Dec  9 21:49 lib -> usr/lib/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Dec  9 21:49 lib64 -> usr/lib64/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Dec  9 21:49 proc/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Dec  9 21:49 root/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Dec  9 21:49 run/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    8 Dec  9 21:49 sbin -> usr/sbin/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3.1K Dec  9 21:49 shutdown*
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Dec  9 21:49 sys/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Dec  9 21:49 sysroot/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Dec  9 21:49 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4.0K Dec  9 21:49 usr/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Dec  9 21:49 var/
```

although I have ended up with the add a dracut hook `usr/lib/dracut/hooks/pre-mount/remove_fs_metadata_csum.sh`, I am still wondering what is reason that my systemd service does not work.

This is what I have done to the initramfs:

```
+ rm -fr /root/initramfs.tmp
+ mkdir -p /root/initramfs.tmp/usr/lib/systemd/system/initrd-root-device.target.wants
+ cd /root/initramfs.tmp
+ sed 's/^  //g'
+ tee usr/lib/systemd/system/test.service
[Service]
ExecStartPre=bash -c -x 'echo ================hihi==========='
+ ln -s ../test.service usr/lib/systemd/system/initrd-root-device.target.wants/
++ uname -r
+ INITFAMFS_PATH=/boot/initramfs-3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64.img
+ cp /boot/initramfs-3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64.img.old /boot/initramfs-3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64.img
+ find . '!' -type d
+ cpio --format=newc --create --verbose
+ tee --append /boot/initramfs-3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64.img
./usr/lib/systemd/system/initrd-root-device.target.wants/test.service
./usr/lib/systemd/system/test.service
2 blocks
+ rm -fr /root/initramfs.tmp
```

It does not work, I could not confirm the output ====hihi==== on next reboot.
Note, I appended a cpio to the initramfs, this works by design, I have successfully done with this method to add a file such as `usr/lib/dracut/hooks/pre-mount/remove_fs_metadata_csum.sh` or overwrite files such as `usr/bin/fsck.ext4`. I have also tried to use `usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service.wants` but not work.

Maybe I need use other dependencies? such as sysinit.target? but I want it be executed before systemd-fsck-root.service anyway.

sorry it is complicated and a rare case. Is there anyone has any information of why a simple service added to initramfs does not work?

EDIT: I have also tried other systemd experiences, such as drop-in conf, neither works.

Comment: I don't think systemd starts services (or maybe systemd itself doesn't start) until after initrd is swapped out for the real root.  That's why you need to use initrd build hooks to inject scripts.  A lot of system binaries may not be available in the initrd as well.

Comment: @user10489 that is a good assumption. However, I have added a kernel option such as rd.break=initqueue or rd.break=cmdline or rd.break=pre-mount to enter the rescue mode, the rootfs has not yet been mounted, in that state, I inspected systemd by `systemctl status`, it showed several service status, and I have even configured a drop-in conf for systemd-fsck-root.service, and it works by this manual way, it just does not work in normal boot.

Comment: If `systemctl status` works, you should be able to find out what targets have fired and used those.  Note that systemd adds implicit dependencies, and likely one or more of them forces your script after the root chroot, so you may need to suppress those.

Comment: that is exactly what I thought, but don't know wha I missed. My service need be run before swap root, and even before systemd-fsck-root.service. I have used many ways to try to trigger my service, considered many things such as `DefaultDependencies=no`, After=... Before=... Wants=... . And even tried the drop-in conf of the systemd-fsck-root.service ( it works in emergency mode), but all just does not work in normal mode, all my systemd experiences does not work, this made me doubt that systemd in the initramfs mode ignore all new services, drop-ins.